# Esper VirtualDataWindowLookup

Tags: java, esper

Hash anyone used Esper VirtualDataWindowLookup . I want to use Cache has my store and do not know how to integrate with VirtaulDataWindows.

Can anyone help me in this regards

I have tried implementing it but the keys are random

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The keys will depend on the EPL query. When the query has, for example, "...where key1=value", the keys that are passed will have the value. There is an example that comes with the distribution.

Comment: Thank You for Answering. But with values how can I fetch my Data Store I would be needing the keys even right.

Comment: Thank you For answering.

Please Ignore my previous Comment.

I have gone through the provided example.
We are getting only the values but how we know for which keys they are mapped to.

Can anyone provide me some working example?

I want to get the values from Cache like Redis or EhCache etc.